# create a string with parameters that depend on a list values in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm new to Python and I would like to create a string like this :

```
print("{} INNER JOIN {}".format(table1, table2))
```

The problem is that `table1` and `table2` are stored in a list `tables_list = ['table1','table2']` and I don't know how many values there are in that list, so if I only have one item in that list, the result of the print would be :

```
table1
```

without the join.

I guess I should be looping on `tables_list` but I can't seem to figure out how to use `format` in that case. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) combined with slicing.

```
" INNER JOIN ".join(tables_list[:2])
```

Though it looks like you are trying to build an SQL query, so I'd warn you you should be wary of rolling your own query builder.  Look in to the docs for whichever DB library you are using to make sure you aren't rewriting things they can already do for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> tables_list = ['table1','table2']
>>> print("{} INNER JOIN {}".format(*tables_list))
table1 INNER JOIN table2
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are writing SQL. To help mitigate the risk of getting SQL injected most Python database libraries offer their own form of string formatting, (a.k.a bind variables). Utilizing bind variables in Python usually looks like this.

```
query_results = cursor.execute("?INNER JOIN ?", ("table1", "table2"))
```